# How to build API documentation for an R package in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, roxygen2

I'm working on a very recent Windows 10 build, RStudio 1.3.959 and I've just installed the latest MikTex.

I'm trying to put together an R package using RStudio. I can build the package and the Function documentation comments are being converted into /man/*.Rd files. These are then successfully displayed when one executes ?function_name in the RStudio console window.

Unfortunately, I'm having very little luck building the PDF package API documentation (not to be mistaken as the vignette; which I can build). I've looked over a good few tutorials but they all stop short of instructing how one builds the final PDF API document that one expects with every R package.

I've tried:
**Build[Windows]->More->Document** ... which execute `devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'vignette'))`

**Build[Windows]->More->Build Source Package** ... which executes `devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'vignette'))` followed by `devtools::build(binary = TRUE, args = c('--preclean'))`

**Build[Windows]->More->Build Binary Package** ... which executes `devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'vignette'))` followed by `devtools::build(binary = TRUE, args = c('--preclean'))`

All three function as expected but still no final package manual pdf file.

Doing some digging on Stack I noticed someone used the command:

```
devtools::build_manual()
```

I'm convinced this is what I need. However, when I execute that line of code I get the error:

```
Converting Rd files to LaTeX ...
Warning in sys2(makeindex, shQuote(idxfile)) : '"makeindex"' not found
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  unable to run 'makeindex' on 'Rd2.idx'
Warning in sys2(makeindex, shQuote(idxfile)) : '"makeindex"' not found
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  unable to run 'makeindex' on 'Rd2.idx'
Error in running tools::texi2pdf()
Error: Failed to build manual
```

Which has left me none the wiser, although it's quite clear that something's a bit upset by the absence of makeindex. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you mean the standard reference manual. For example [ggplot2 reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf). In my experience, this is thrown together by CRAN when you submit. All the manual is (as far as I can tell) a collection of things that a well documented package should have, such as a DESCRIPTION file, a NAMESPACE file, and the various .RD files for actual documentation.

Even when looking at the public [github for ggplot2](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2) we see that they do not have the manual in their repository. Additionally, there isn't any evidence in their `.git*ignore` files to suggest they made the manual themselves.

However, if you want to make this yourself  `devtools::build_manual()` is the correct function call.

I was able to make the manual with a preexisting package on github. I would suggest trying to reinstall your `devtools` package and make sure there are no warnings or errors. It may be helpful to run a session as administrator to insure things get installed correctly.

Good luck!

---

I am using R version 3.4 with RStudio 1.1.453 on MacOS High Serra.

Comment: Thank you, Justin. That certainly explains where the reference manual comes from.  I'm somewhat overwhelmed by the package documentation R spits out. A manuscript describing the package is being submitted to the Journal of Statistical Software, plus the in-package roxygen descriptions for help (?function_name), plus a vignette, plus a space on github. A lot of this will be repeats and to be honest, I'm not sure what's the best strategy for publishing, demonstrating and making available this particular package.

Comment: Also big thanks - reinstalling devtools did the trick.

Comment: Welcome to being a package maintainer! :)